# How should I rewrite this code to connect to Netsuite with access token?

Tags: java, netsuite

```
public static WsClient getWsClient() throws MalformedURLException {

    ConfigurationParser parser = ConfigurationParser.getInstance();

    WsClient client = new WsClient(new URL(parser.getProperty("netsuite.url")));

    Credentials credentials = new Credentials(parser.getProperty("netsuite.email"),
            parser.getProperty("netsuite.password"));

    String account = parser.getProperty("netsuite.account");

    String role = parser.getProperty("netsuite.role");

    Passport passport = new Passport(credentials, account, role);

    client.setRequestLevelCredentials(passport);

    client.setApplicationId(parser.getProperty("netsuite.applicationId"));

    return client;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Why would you like to rewrite this piece of code, is it not working? What problem are you facing?

Comment: Please try to ask a specific question based on your owm attempt to solve this problem. What kind of research did you do; what documentation did you consult? Where are you stuck? Asking to transform code X to code Y is too broad. Refer to [How to Ask a Good Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: @AtomHeartFather It's working but our company is about to change this option of connection to the access token option, I'm pretty new to automation development and trying to learn by myself and with google's help...